# Determine for which k the application is linear

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I'm trying to solve this exercise.

Determine for which $k$ the application is linear

$T(x, y, z) = ((\kappa + 2)x^2 + z, \kappa y, 4 + x + y − \kappa^2)$ For each $(x, y, z) \in\mathbb R^3$

> The given solution is $k = 2$

I know that the condition of linearity to check are:

1. $T(v + w) = T(v) + T(w)$
2. $AT(v) = T(Av)$ for each $A ∈ R$

so considering $v = (x, y, z)$, $w = (a, b, c)$ the previous condition have to be verifired.

#### Checking the first consition i end up with this system

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{}
{k + 2 = 0} &  \\ 
{k^2 -4 = 0} & \\
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

so $k = -2$

#### Checking the second consition i end up with this system

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{}
{(k + 2)x^2 + z = A(k + 2)x^2 + z} &  \\ 
{Aky = Aky} & \\
{4 - k^2 = A(k - k^2)} & \\
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

That is verified only for $A = 1$.

To me it seems that is not linear, am i missing something?

Comment: To begin with, $T(0)=0$. Then, nothing with $x^2$ can be linear. on the right hand side of the first equation in the expansion of your second condition, there must be $A^2$ that can only be true if $k+2=0$.

Comment: Sry but didn't understand, am i right that this is not linear or the given solution $k = 2$ is correct? By the way i simplified $A^2$ with the $A$ that was on the left side. The initial equation was: $A((k+2)x^2 + z) = (k+2)x^2 A^2 + zA$

Comment: Your map $T$ is linear if and only if $k=-2$ as you have correctly determined from the additivity condition (1). You seem to have made a mistake when expanding the third equation in homogeneity condition (2).

Comment: @Mat.C Ok, then you need $k+2=0$ for that to be true for *every* $A$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like others have noted in the comment, we have that $T$ is linear if and only if $k + 2 = 0.$

Given that $k + 2 = 0,$ we have that $k^2 - 4 = (k - 2)(k + 2) = 0$ so that $T(x, y, z) = (z, -2y, x + y).$ One can easily verify that $T(a(x_1, y_1, z_1) + b(x_2, y_2, z_2)) = aT(x_1, y_1, z_1) + bT(x_2, y_2, z_2),$ hence $T$ is linear.

Given that $T$ is linear, we have that $(k + 2, 0, 3 - k^2) = T(-1, 0, 0) = -T(1, 0, 0) = -(k + 2, 0, 5 - k^2)$ so that $k + 2 = -(k + 2)$ and $3 - k^2 = k^2 - 5,$ from which it follows that $k + 2 = 0.$